# why I cannot set up an accessory view in my static UITableViewCell in viewDidLoad method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a tableview with 3 static `UITableViewCell`s. I want to set a checkmark on the first cell when user enters that panel. In my `viewDidLoad()` method I'm calling:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))?.accessoryType = .checkmark
```

but the checkmark is not there. How can I assign it from the code then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your setting code directly to UITableView delegate (`cellForRow`), do not call in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @user3766930 sorry i do not know the solution for your question. Why do you need to use static cell?